# Multiple Jenkins builds per commit

Tags: git, jenkins

I've got a Jenkins instance that has over 200 freestyle projects. We do our work in feature branches that get merged into e.g. `master`. Most of our merges are fast-forward merges. Most projects are setup to execute a build script followed by the execution of a deploy script. The deploy script will look at `$GIT_BRANCH` and if the branch is one of the deployable branches (such as `master`) then it will deploy it, otherwise it does nothing. This means that commits pushed to the feature branch only have the build step done, whereas commits added to `master` will get a build done followed by a deploy. We're using the Atlassian Bitbucket Server Integration plugin to trigger builds from our Bitbucket Server repos.

I've noticed that typically after commits in a feature branch have been built, once the branch is merged into `master` Jenkins will refuse to do a build because the commit that's now in the `master` branch has already been built in the feature branch and therefore Jenkins refuses to build it again. That means that the change is never deployed because the deploy script doesn't run on the feature branch, only on the `master` branch, which is where it gets skipped.

Is there a good solution to ensuring builds happen in the `master` branch even if they've been built before?

I realize that we should move to Jenkinsfiles, but that involves porting many projects over so I'm hoping there's a less time-consuming solution to this.